# What is this shell doing and how to find it out?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Today my server slowed down greatly. Most resource-consuming are - surprisingly - two shells. Two ZSH processes on TTY 0 (what does that mean?).

```
> ps axjf
12474  8947 16532 16532 ?           -1 Sl    1000   0:34          \_ /usr/bin/xfce4
-terminal
 8947  8953 16532 16532 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00          |   \_ gnome-pty-
helper
 8947 24044 24044 24044 ?           -1 Rs    1000  87:01          |   \_ zsh
 8947 24176 24176 24176 ?           -1 Rs    1000  86:45          |   \_ zsh
 8947 31137 31137 31137 pts/2     2313 Ss    1000   0:00          |   \_ zsh
31137  2313  2313 31137 pts/2     2313 R+    1000   0:00          |       \_ ps
```

[image: htop reports]

**Before I kill these, how to find out what are they doing?**

#### Running:

1. Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
2. ZSH (version says zsh 5.1.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)) with Oh-My-ZSH
3. Kernel, dm, etc.
   inxi -S -xxx
   System: Host: T420s Kernel: 4.4.0-104-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0) Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.28) info: xfce4-panel dm: lightdm Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial

Comment: Uninstall OMZ and your problems will magically disappear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before I kill these, how to find out what are they doing?

`strace` them, for starters.  In a pinch, use a debugger.

> what does that mean?

It means that they have no controlling terminal.  Given that they are children of XFCE Terminal (right there as `/usr/bin/xfce4-terminal` in your process tree), you should also look to the terminal emulator sessions on your GUI.

Comment: I thought as much but I'm only using Terminator and I closed down ALL it's windows. Additionally, when I did `echo $$` in them, I got different PIDs. Unless I misunderstand "terminal emulator sessions". Am following up on `strace` now, thank you.